# How to improve Burrows-Wheeler Transform performance?

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation, compression

I have implemented the [Burrows-Wheeler Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform) as below:

```
eofChar = FromCharacterCode[255];

BurrowsWheelerTransform[string_] :=
 With[{s = string <> eofChar},
  StringJoin @@ (StringPart[#, -1] & /@ Sort[NestList[
       StringRotateLeft[#, 1] &, s, StringLength[s] - 1]
      , LexicographicOrder])]

InverseBurrowsWheelerTransform[string_] :=
 With[{len = StringLength[string], c = Characters[string]},
  StringJoin @@ Most[SelectFirst[Nest[
      SortBy[Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[#], c]], 
        s |-> StringJoin @@ s, LexicographicOrder] &, {}, 
      len], #[[-1]] == eofChar &]]
  ]

bwt = BurrowsWheelerTransform["swiss miss is on a mission to mississippi"]
(*"nssaosn ss mwmsmp   oot ipississsiiiiiÿ si"*)

InverseBurrowsWheelerTransform[bwt]
(*"swiss miss is on a mission to mississippi"*)
```

However, this implementation is very slow for larger strings especially in the inverse transform. I suspect this is due to all this `Transpose` business with column insertion. Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: I suspect you will need to use a new algorithm for performance.  Here is one algorithm that promises better performance: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866715000052